# How to left join same table on different rows in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I need to fix following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_treads
LEFT JOIN usernames ON usernames.uid=message_treads.uid_1
LEFT JOIN usernames ON usernames.uid=message_treads.uid_2
```

I know i should use aliases, but i am not sure on how to do it here. I know how to do it when there is only one left join of one table, but how to to it when there are more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, you need to use aliases like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_treads
LEFT JOIN usernames uid1 ON uid1.uid=message_treads.uid_1
LEFT JOIN usernames uid2 ON uid2.uid=message_treads.uid_2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_treads
LEFT JOIN usersnames ON usernames.uid IN (message_treads.uid_1, message_tread.uid_2)
```

As for aliasing, you'd do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM message_treads
LEFT JOIN usernames AS user1 ON user1.uid = message_treads.uid_1
LEFT JOIN usernames AS user2 ON user2.uid = message_treads.uid_2
```

But that's probably not what you want, as this'll return two sets of columns from the doubled-up usernames tables. The first version above will return only one set of username columns.

Comment: It might be exactly what they want, if there are two distinct users (say, sender and receiver) associated with each message.

Comment: I prefer ts answer, using "AS" makes it more readable. I'd like to add that the OP should also only select the required columns, never *